# How to use asyncio module to parse website in python?

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio

I want to parse one website, so I have written two versions of parser(one with asyncio, second without). But async code performs code more or same as without async parser. Some details in code in russian, think that there is no problem.  I have started work with asyncio today. Help me.

This code with asyncio:

```
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import *
import pprint
import time

url = "https://besmart.kz"

def get_html(url):
    req = Request(url)
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    return html

async def get_stock_data(i):
    html = get_html(url + i['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    stock_data = {}

    try:
        stock_data["Old price"] = soup.find('span', class_='line-through red').find('span', class_='text-muted greyColor').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Old price"] = "Отсутствует"
    try:
        stock_data["Price"] = soup.find('div', id='calc-price', class_='price').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Price"] = "Ошибка"
    try:
        stock_data["Title"] = soup.find('div', class_='title').find('h1', itemprop='name').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Title"] = "Ошибка"
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    pp.pprint(stock_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    install_opener(opener)

    stock_list = []

    for i in range(1,4):
        html = get_html(url + "/?page=" + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        stock_list.extend(soup.find_all('a', class_='deal__discount-kz'))

    ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        start = time.time()
        coroutines = [ioloop.create_task(get_stock_data(i)) for i in stock_list]
        ioloop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coroutines))
    finally:
        ioloop.close()
        print(f"Время выполнения: {time.time() - start}")
```

This cide without:

```
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import *
import pprint
import time

url = "https://besmart.kz"

def get_html(url):
    req = Request(url)
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    return html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    install_opener(opener)

    stock_list = []

    for i in range(1,4):
        html = get_html(url + "/?page=" + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        stock_list.extend(soup.find_all('a', class_='deal__discount-kz'))
    start = time.time()
    for i in stock_list:
        html = get_html(url + i['href'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        stock_data = {}

        try:
            stock_data["Old price"] = soup.find('span', class_='line-through red').find('span', class_='text-muted greyColor').text.strip()
        except:
            stock_data["Old price"] = "Отсутствует"
        try:
            stock_data["Price"] = soup.find('div', id='calc-price', class_='price').text.strip()
        except:
            stock_data["Price"] = "Ошибка"
        try:
            stock_data["Title"] = soup.find('div', class_='title').find('h1', itemprop='name').text.strip()
        except:
            stock_data["Title"] = "Ошибка"

        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
        pp.pprint(stock_data)

    print(f"Время выполнения: {time.time() - start}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify things with the `aiohttp` module. For example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
import time

url = "https://besmart.kz"
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

async def get_html(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS) as resp:
            return await resp.text()

async def get_stock_data(i):
    response = await get_html(url + i['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    stock_data = {}

    try:
        stock_data["Old price"] = soup.find('span', class_='line-through red').find('span', class_='text-muted greyColor').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Old price"] = "Отсутствует"
    try:
        stock_data["Price"] = soup.find('div', id='calc-price', class_='price').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Price"] = "Ошибка"
    try:
        stock_data["Title"] = soup.find('div', class_='title').find('h1', itemprop='name').text.strip().replace('\u2009','')
    except:
        stock_data["Title"] = "Ошибка"
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    pp.pprint(stock_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stock_list = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    

    for i in range(1, 4):
        html = loop.run_until_complete(get_html(url + "/?page=" + str(i)))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        stock_list.extend(soup.find_all('a', class_='deal__discount-kz'))

    try:
        start = time.time()
        coroutines = [loop.create_task(get_stock_data(i)) for i in stock_list]
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coroutines))
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print(f"Время выполнения: {time.time() - start}")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!